# Solr: Custom RequestHandler within the Solr api (solrj) that makes a query call back to the server

Tags: solr, solrj

I'm looking for some advice on a specific issue that is holding us back.

I'm trying to create a custom RequestHandler within the Solr api (solrj) that makes a query call back to the server.

I'm not finding any good, run-able examples of this on-line. Possibly I'm approaching this wrong. Any advice would be appreciated.

Here is one of my attempts to coding this.

```
  public void handleRequestBody(SolrQueryRequest req, SolrQueryResponse rsp) throws Exception
  { 

    SolrCore solrServerCore = req.getCore();
    SolrRequestHandler handler = solrServerCore.getRequestHandler("/select");

    ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
    params1.add("q", "*:*");

    SolrQueryRequest req = new LocalSolrQueryRequest(solrServerCore, params);
    SolrQueryResponse rsp = new SolrQueryResponse();;
    solrServerCore.execute(handler1, req, rsp);

    //!!! Not returning a structured response
    System.out.println(rsp.toString());
    System.out.println(rsp.getReturnFields());
    System.out.println(rsp.getValues().toString());
}
```

Comment: So you want to create a RequestHandler that receives your query and fires another query right? And what should you do after that? since Solr is exposing an HTTP API you should send some response back to the client at least acknowledging that you've received the request and that you're working on that, for instance returning an HTTP 202 Accepted or an HTTP 102 Processing response codes. But I think you should provide a little more info about your end goal.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

All I'm trying to do is query the data to see what are all of the values used by some specific fields and then construct a XML response to send back to the user. To get the information that I need I have to do more than one query and process some of the data returned. That is why I am using a RequestHandler.

My queries work fine individually. But the issue is I'm having trouble using the objects available within the RequestHandler to make the call back to the server. The response is always 0 documents no matter how simple/broad my query is. e.g. "q", "*:*"

Comment: Sorry in that code snippet, the execute statement should be using "handler" not "handler1".

Comment: Are you running Solr in a distributed environment? or you have one single instance? Because if you want to do several queries against the index you can fire the queries without the need of firing yet another request. Other way of looking at this is, you need to hit a different endpoint to gather the data? like aggregating data from a different collection?

Comment: This is in a distributed environment, on the cloud.

Comment: Does it make any sense to create an EmbeddedSolrServer instance in the RequestHandler in order to run a query against the server?

Comment: Not really, the EmbeddedSolrServer has a different use in my opiniong, take a look at this [SOLR-1093](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1093) this is quite old but could put you on the right track, also keep in mind that you may need to think how your component is going to handle itself in the distributed environment. BTW when you say distributed is because you have replicas and shards and a full featured SolrCloud cluster?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Solr. 
We usually run our server in Linux VM. 
start as: 
sudo bin/solr start -c -m 256m.
We run the command
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=sagewell&numShards=8&maxShardsPerNode=8"
To create 8 shards for the server.

Currently I am developing the code by running a unit test QuickHandlerTest against my QuickHandler extends RequestHandlerBase

I get the core by 
SolrCore core = req.getCore();
I attempt to run the SolrQueryRequest by the execute method.
core.execute(selectHandler, req1, rsp1);